# reduce list of lists to a single list in scala

Tags: scala, list

How can I reduce list of (name, value) lists in scala like below

For e.g.

```
[(a,1), (b,2), (c,4)] 
[(a,2), (b,3), (c,4)]
[(a,1), (b,3), (c,4)]
```

reduced to a list of (name, maximum occurred value in all lists, (number of occurrences/total occurrences))

```
[(a,1,.66), (b,3,0.66), (c,4,1)]
```

Can be any of the values if the ratio of their occurrences is same.

I have tried this below. I created a single list l and

```
l.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.groupBy(_._2)).mapValues(_.mapValues(_.size)).toList.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toList))
```

which gives me

```
List((b,List((2,1), (3,2))), (a,List((2,1), (1,2))), (c,List((4,3))))
```

I think I am close but a quick help would be appreciated

Comment: Any specific problems with the solution that you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get what you need:

```
val lol = List(
  List( ("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 4) ), 
  List( ("a", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 4) ),
  List( ("a", 1), ("b", 3), ("c", 4) )
)

val list = lol.flatten

val t1Map = list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.size)

val tupleMap = list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).
  map{ case ((x, y), c) =>  ((x, y), c.toDouble / t1Map(x)) }.
  groupBy(_._1._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).max)

// tupleMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(
//   b -> 0.6666666666666666, a -> 0.6666666666666666, c -> 1.0
// )
```

[UPDATE]

To capture the entire tuples with corresponding max occurrences, here's a different approach:

```
val tupleMap = list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
// tupleMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, Int),Int] = Map(
//   (b,2) -> 1, (a,2) -> 1, (c,4) -> 3, (a,1) -> 2, (b,3) -> 2
// )

val t1Map = list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.size)
// t1Map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 3, a -> 3, c -> 3)

val t1MapMax = tupleMap.groupBy(_._1._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).max)
// t1MapMax: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 2, a -> 2, c -> 3)

val resultMap = tupleMap.filter{ case (k, v) => v == t1MapMax(k._1) }.
  map{ case (k, v) => (k._1, k._2, v.toDouble / t1Map(k._1) ) }
// resultMap: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(String, Int, Double)] = List(
//   (c,4,1.0), (a,1,0.6666666666666666), (b,3,0.6666666666666666)
// )
```

Comment: How can I also get the highest occurred value? For e.g. (b,3,0.666)

Comment: Got it working by this below

`list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).map{case ((x,y),c) => ((x,y),c.toDouble/t1Map(x))}.groupBy(_._1._1).mapValues(k => k.toSeq.maxBy(_._2)).values`

Comment: My bad, didn't notice that you wanted the entire tuples with max occurrences.  There are various ways to do it.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Even better. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to apply some high order magic in a one-liner likewise:

```
scala> elems
res1: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,2), (d,1), (b,3), (a,4), (d,5))

scala> elems.groupBy(_._1).map(tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._2.map(_._2).max, tuple._2.length/(elems.length:Float)))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Char, Int, Float)] = List((b,3,0.16666667), (d,5,0.33333334), (a,4,0.5))
```

Basically, the first `groupBy` groups each word by its elements in a map.

```
scala> val groupedElems = elems.groupBy(_._1)
groupedElems: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,List[(Char, Int)]] = Map(b -> List((b,3)), d -> List((d,1), (d,5)), a -> List((a,1), (a,2), (a,4)))
```

After that, we have all the information to build our final solution:

```
scala> groupedElems.map(tuple => 
 |   (tuple._1 // I want the name
 |  , tuple._2.map(_._2).max // along with the max
 |  , tuple._2.length / (elems.length: Float) // and the occurrences
 |  )
 | )
res33: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Char, Int, Float)] =
      List((b,3,0.16666667), (d,5,0.33333334), (a,4,0.5))
```

Comment: Output is incorrect. According to your input the output I am expecting is List ((a,1 or 2 or 4,.333), (b,3,1), (d, 1 or 5, 0.5))

Comment: Mmm... I guess I didn't understand what you meant by occurrences, is it by `String` or the whole tuple? Anyways, I think both answers have given a neat starting point for you to address your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I did't want the max of second element. I want the element with max occurrences.